# jQuery: Call and Uncall a Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following code to call a function when the screen is less than 200 but I can't disable the function when the scroll is more than 200.

```
function animateHeader() {
    $(selector)
        .animate({ opacity: 0.0, bottom: 70 }, { duration: 600 })
        .animate({ opacity: 0.0, bottom: 50 }, { duration: 0 })
        .animate({ opacity: 0.0, bottom: 70 }, { duration: 600, complete: animateHeader })
    }

    $window.on('scroll', function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 200) {   
           animateHeader();
        } else {
           // Disable animateHeader()
        }
    }); // Finish scroll
```

I know there are alternatives to not call a function here in this case, but is it possible to disable a function when it's already active?

Comment: You need to call `animate()` again, setting the `opacity` and `position` to the original values. There is no 'undo' operation to do it for you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that's a good idea, but Kapantzak's solution seems to be effective to uncall a function.

Comment: @Callum. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: It doesn't 'uncall' a function - thats not possible FYI. It simply stops the animation.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That pretty much does it, it forces the function to stop working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `stop()` function:

```
else {
   $(selector).stop();
}
```